# Stuck. New to JS. Trying to figure this out since hours

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, string-length, global-object

I can't solve exercise three and four. I would be very pleased to get some help. Thank you in advance!

```
function exerciseThree(str){
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: str
  // On the next line create a variable called 'length' and using the length property assign the new variable to the length of str


  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return length; 
}

function exerciseFour(num1){
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: num1
  // On the next line create a variable called 'rounded'. Call the Math global object's round method, passing it num1, and assign it to the rounded variable.
  var num1 = rounded;
  math.round (num1); 

  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return rounded;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be very good instructions already. Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: There are many javascript tutorials online, you should work through them to learn it, if these exercises are too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These exercises are trying to teach you how to declare variables and how to assign values to them.

Variables are like little containers that hold values for you. For example, I can make a little container to hold your name. And since one of the ways to declare a variable in JavaScript is to use the `var` keyword, I could write something as following:

```
var name = "Sevr";
```

I made a container with `var` keyword and named it `name`. This `name` container now holds your name which is `Sevr`. Instead of typing `Sevr` over and over again you can now type `Name` over and over. But, this doesn't make much difference. `Sevr` and `name` both contain same number of characters. It makes more sense to have your variables contain information that you don't want to type over and over again.

So exercise three wants you to declare a variable named length and make it hold the length of any string that it is provided with.

```
function exerciseThree(str) {
        var length = str.length
        return length;
}
```

This function above takes a string, you make a variable named `length` that contains the length of that string.

Now if we pass it any string it will tell us what length they are. If we pass it your name `Sevr` and `name` and we will see that they both return 4:

```
exerciseThree("name") // 4
exerciseThree("Sevr") // 4
```

On the fourth exercise, the concept is the same. The exercise wants to teach you that you can make a simple variable name that can hold on to some complex value for you. This time it wants you to declare variable named rounded that holds on to the rounded value of a number.

```
function exerciseFour(num1) {
    var rounded = Math.round(num1)
    return rounded;
}
```

And, now if you pass a number with decimals to this function it will round it for you.

```
exerciseFour(4.5) // 5
```

Answer (score -2):

These exercises are worded in a really confusing way. Where you getting them from?

Anyway, here're the answers, hope they help:

```
function exerciseThree(str){
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: str
  // On the next line create a variable called 'length' and using the length property assign the new variable to the length of str
  var length = str.length
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return length; 
}

function exerciseFour(num1){
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: num1
  // On the next line create a variable called 'rounded'. Call the Math global object's round method, passing it num1, and assign it to the rounded variable.
  var rounded = Math.round(num1)
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return rounded;
}
```